# Sharepoint 2013 Search Issues when filter on path

Tags: web-part, search

Currently we have a problem regarding the sharepoint search service. We have two domains to access our sharepoint server (one for intranet users and one for Internet users).

Lets say the two URLs are like this:

- Intranet -> local.xxx
- Internet -> extern.xxx

If we use a search web part (webpart->search->search results) then we only get valid results if we browse through local.xxx but if we execute the search web part through extern.xxx then we get no results. *So lets assume the search webpart is accessable through https:// local.xxx/search1 and https:// extern.xxx/search1 then just https:// local.xxx/search1 returns results.*

In the search web part we use this expression to filter (the local default result source) -> **path:"https:// local.xxx/projekte"  contentclass:"STS_Site" contentclass:"STS_Web"**

If I remove the path part of the Expression the Expression works for extern.xxx to but of course won´t filter just project websites.

I can't figure out how to configure this Expression to work for both domains. Things I have already tried:

- path:projekte
- path:"projekte"
- path:projekte*
- path:projekte*
- path:/projekte*
- path:https:// extern.xxx/projekte
- path:"https:// extern.xxx/projekte*"

The only thing which works is **path:https://** but this do not filter my resultset.

What have I already tried to fix this:

- I have checked the search service start address (to match the default domain)
  Both addresses are https:// local.xxx
  I also triggerd a full search rebuild
- I have tried to create a property "PagePath" which is the same as Path but do not need a perfect match (found a post on this page which suggest that)
- I have tried to examine the SharePoint logs to find differences or maybe errors when searching through extern.xxx

I am a little bit confused what to try next...
Did someone have a suggestion what I can check next to fix this problem? 
Or maybe a workaround? What we need is a search resultset containing all pages below a Folder (like the following):

- https:// intern.xxx/projekte/Projekt1
- https:// inter.xxx/projekte/Projekt1/Subprojet1